# How can distance correlation be used to develop a model?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, correlation

I've been reading up on [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) recently; it's being billed as a way of testing if two variables are related in a non-linear fashion.
Now, for a (non-zero) standard correlation coefficient, you know that a linear model will capture some of the behavior.  As far as I can tell, there is no similarly straightforward way to figure out the form of the model you should be using for two variables that have non-zero distance correlation. Is there such a way, or do you have to break out your other model-building techniques?